# SPSS: How do I change a case_i-variable_j depending on the values of other case_variables

Tags: macos, spss

If SPSS only had indices for its cases and variables (rows and columns) and the value of a case is represented as Val(i.j) then I would like to run scripts like

```
for loop = 10 to 100 
 If Val(loop+10,6)=0 then
  Val(loop, 10)= Val(loop+3, 8) 'or something like this
 end if
next loop
```

I am new to SPSS and noted that you can shift columns and then use a repeat and compute.
But compute will affect the whole column and I would like changing selected cases looping through all cases (and using IF (combination of case vales = true) then...... )
So something like VBA has for Excel.It seems VBA is not available in SPSs for OSX (can't locate if it is)

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do, but SPSS has the `$casenum` variable for record indexing; so you may use `if $casenum = [some condition] [some transformation]`

Comment: If you add a more specific example from your real data (you can do that by editing your post) we may be able to offer a solution and explain it, so you can understand the principle and generalize it.